# Friend parent class cannot access private constructor in child

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

I want to create a parent class `Base` which has factories for its subclasses `Derived1`, `Derived2` etc. The constructor of `Base` and all its derived classes should be private. I try to do it this way:

base.h:

```
class Derived1;    

class Base
{
    protected:
        Base ();

    public:
        Base *createDerived1 ();
}

#include "derived1.h"
```

derived1.h:

```
#include "base.h"    

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    friend class Base;

    private:
        Derived1 ();
}
```

derived1.cpp:

```
Derived1::Derived1 ()
    : Base ()
{

}
```

base.cpp:

```
Base *Base::createDerived1 ()
{
    return new Derived1 (); // error C2248: 'Derived1::Derived1' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Derived1'
}
```

However, I cannot access the private constructor inside the factory, despite declaring `Base` a friend class of `Derived1`. Am I doing something wrong, or there is no possibility to have the parent class as friend and I should make constructors of `Derived` classes public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works for me:

```
//B.h 
class D;

class B{

protected:
  B(){}

public:
static  B* f();

};

//D.h
class D: public B{
 friend class B;

  private:
  D():B(){}

};

//B.cpp
B*  B::f(){
 D *d=new D;
 return d;
}
```

Your one bug is identified by the other reply. Another is the factory methods should be `static`, since you will not be able to create `Base` objects due to the fact that it has *private* constructor.

Comment: Right, but actually the 'Base' constructor in my code is 'protected', I posted it incorrectly as 'private'. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: But I declared Base as a friend of Derived, which should provide access to all elements of Derived to Base, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, actually, the factory method does work without being static, but you are correct since it should be static by definition.

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy, I don't understand, if u cant create any object, how you will call a *non-static* method of the class? could u plz clarify?

Comment: I meant that it does compile.

Answer (score 0):

That was indeed a silly mistake on my part, I wrote:

```
Base *createDerived1 ()
{
    return new Derived1 (); // error C2248: 'Derived1::Derived1' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Derived1'
}
```

instead of

```
Base *Base::createDerived1 ()
{
    return new Derived1 (); // everything fine
}
```

Of course, the private constructor could not be accessed from the global scope.